# Laravel returning object to javascript getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&' error

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I am making a call to my db, saving the results in an array.
When I try to use my results in the front end I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'` error
I have been trying different combinations of decode or encode on the backend and JSON.parse and stringify on the front end.  What am I doing wrong?

My backend code

```
        $data = [];
        $data['service'] = DB::table('servicingdata')->get();
        $data['loans'] = DB::table('loandata')->get();
        return view('welcome', $data);
```

My front end code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            console.log({{$loans}})
        </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need print html in blade lavarel, you need do this:

**Displaying Unescaped Data**

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's **htmlspecialchars** function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

for more info, [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data).

Comment: Thanks, I have been going the complete wrong way on this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `{!! $loans !!}` to display the unescaped data. By using `{{ }}` your data will be processed by `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS attacks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log({!! $loans !!});
</script>
```